# show list selected no of list box on each checked

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have a `asp:CheckBoxList` which load items from database.

I want to write a script which shows no. of checked checkbox on each check.
My aspx page is as following :

```
<div id="rfd-demo-zone2" class="placeholderContent accordionEmpGroup-child-subGroup-container">
   <asp:CheckBoxList  ID="ckbList2DesignationUc" runat="Server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" ></asp:CheckBoxList>          
</div>
```

**script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ckbList2DesignationUc input:checked').each(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });
</script>
```

In the above script I am trying to get an alert, but it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Put script in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to ensure the availability of html elements to script and use [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to find the checkboxes of the checkboxlist.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[id*=ckbList2DesignationUc]:checked').each(function () {
            alert('hi');
        });
     });
</script>
```

To fire event on change of checkbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[id*=ckbList2DesignationUc]').change(function () {
            alert(this.id);
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Check if you have latest code and how many checkboxes are checked when page loads?

Comment: none, actually its a kind of app in which selection of the box depend on the user type so i want to write a script which detect the no of checked checkbox and on the basis of role it'll compare it with the limit and will show the popup if the limit will exceed with the allowed number.

Comment: Add alert($('[id*=ckbList2DesignationUc]:checked').length); to next line of  $(document).ready(function(){

Comment: not working :
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert($('[id*=ckbList2DesignationUc]:checked').length);
    });

Comment: Did you get alert? If not then check if you can use jQuery?

Comment: on the same page i am using another jquery script and thats working fine

Comment: I have updated my answer with change event Add that and check if you get alert on changing checkboxes of CheckBoxList, also try to debug javascript to see what exactly going on

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
<div id="rfd-demo-zone2" class="placeholderContent accordionEmpGroup-child-subGroup-container">
      <asp:CheckBoxList  ID="ckbList2DesignationUc" runat="Server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" >
      </asp:CheckBoxList>          
 </div>
```

and access it:

```
 $("#<%=ckbList2DesignationUc.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {  
      alert('checked');
  });
```

Comment: but how can i call alert on check

Comment: try now, removed this.find

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

**Solution-1** 
Whenever you will check checkbox an alert will show you the values of checked items in checkboxes.

Javascript code :

< script type="text/javascript">

```
         function itemClick(radioButton) {
             var Control;
             var selectedItems;
             selectedItems = '';
             Control = document.getElementById("<%=ckbList2DesignationUc.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName("input");
             for (var i = 0; i < Control.length; i++) {
                 if (Control[i].checked == true)
                     selectedItems += i.toString()+',';
             }
             alert(selectedItems);
         }

</script>
```

ASPX Code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            ckbList2DesignationUc.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item" + index, index.ToString()));
        }
        foreach (ListItem Li in ckbList2DesignationUc.Items)
        {
            Li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return itemClick()");
        }

    }
```

Required solution by using Jquery :

**Solution -2**

```
< script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedCheckBoxes = '';
        $('#ckbList2DesignationUc').each(function () {
            var items = new Array();
            $(this).find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    selectedCheckBoxes += $(this).val() + ",";
                    alert(selectedCheckBoxes);
                });
            });
        });

    });
< /script>

< asp:CheckBoxList  ID="ckbList2DesignationUc" runat="Server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%">
                < /asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: I have provide two solution for your problem. Kindly vote up the answer if your problem is resolved or let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Client side:**

```
 $('.CheckBoxList').each(function () {
           var items = new Array();
               $(this).find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                   if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
                        items[items.length] = $(this).next().html();
                     }
                   });
                   $(this).parent().find('.txtList').val(items.toString());
             });
```

**Html MarkUp:**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtabc" CssClass="txtList txtformatcss" Width="160px" ViewStateMode="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkabc" runat="server"                                      
         RepeatLayout="Flow" CssClass="CheckBoxList">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Here  `CheckBoxList` is class name which have given in checkboxlist control

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: you can use it in code behind file as well as inside the script tag `enable AutoPostBack property of checkboxlist to true`

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i=0;            
    foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
            i++;
    }
    Response.Write(i);           
}
```